# SharePoint's "Open in desktop app" is not available in Office 2021 apps, how to show it?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, sharepoint, microsoft-office-2021

I have been shared with a file in SharePoint but the `Open in desktop app` option is invisible. I appreciate any idea to fix it. Only these menu entries are visible in Excel:

[image: Visible menu entries]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What version of Office subscription did you use in desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be the same as in the post
[Office 365 Web Apps: 'Open in desktop app' missing for external users](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2344928-office-365-web-apps-open-in-desktop-app-missing-for-external-users).

You're probably missing this option :

[image]

This is the answer that was given :

> E1 Microsoft licenses don't allow for the use of desktop Office
> software, and to my knowledge they never have.  It doesn't matter what
> you send to these external users, if they aren't paying for access to
> said desktop software, then Office documents won't give them the
> option to open that way.  If they have E3 or E5 licenses, and the
> appropriate Office software installed, then they should be fine.
>
> Now, if the parties having this trouble do hold E3 or E5 licenses,
> they need to speak with Microsoft.

This probably means that the license of your company is
not enough for showing this option.
It might also be that your Office version is insufficient.

You should get in contact with the SharePoint administrator
and ask for a solution.